# How to save a dynamic web page (Cordova App)

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I created an App for projects and To Do lists. It consists of one HTML page, which only has an "add To Do list"-button.
The user can click on that button and create a To Do list, in this list he can create tasks.
The lists and tasks are dynamically generated HTML Elements.

Is there a way to just store everything, the dynamically generated DOM and all its elements and their functions? I searched for an answer for hours and all I found was a method to store data locally with  localStorage: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#localStorage

Since my elements contain a lot of js functions, it would be very complicated to store everything with this method...
Is there no way of storing "the whole thing"?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your question require a very large explanation, anyway I would tell you some tips you can use to step forward since I worked on a similar app last year.

1. Think about a database structure for your app. I got a table "Tasks" in which I stored both tasks and subtasks (task inside other tasks). I also stored alarms (if a task need an alarm), texts, checked/unchecked, archived flag, deleted flag, and so on. Everything you can associate to a task, you need a column for it.
2. Think about your data amount globally. If you plan to store a large amount of data (more or less 5MB) you better choose SQLite approach. If you think your data will not reach this edge, think about LocalStorage. You can google both to manage their use.
3. When the user fill the DOM to create a task and click on "create" (or something similar), you have to "scan" the DOM, acquire all info for the task created and put them into your DB
4. When the user want to update/modify a task, you have to find it in the DB, fetch related data, create the DOM's structures you need to show data, fill the structures with data

These are more or less few tips I can give you on your long way. Good luck

Comment: Thank you, those are very helpful tips! The database seems to be the only option... I wanted to keep my app simple and therefore an easier solution would be great...